# Learning the samples can be predicted most accurately

Tags: machine-learning

The goal of making machine learning algorithms is mostly to try to make accurate predictions for all unseen samples.

What if the goal is to determine a subset of the unseen samples so that the prediction will be most accurate for this subset and ignore the rest that is hard to make accurate predictions.

Is there a field of study for this type of problem?

Comment: Might you be looking for a narrow conditional distribution?

Comment: IIUC, you refer to supervised problems, and you have a trained model $M$, and now you want to have some tool that, for a given $\mathbf x$, tells you how reliable the prediction of $M$ for that $\mathbf x$ would be? Many models give you a score of how confident they are about their prediction, so in this case, you could just apply $M$ and check the score, right?

Comment: No. I don't even want to make predictions on the samples that are hard  to predict. Most ML methods will still make predictions on those hard to predict samples, which drags the performance on those easy to predict samples. In other words, as an extreme, if I can even find one sample that is highly accurately predicted, I am happy. I don't care about what the predictions of the rest n-1 samples would be.